# Can I unvote/remove a downvote or upvote I gave?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

If somebody accidentally clicked on a upvote or downvote, how can they fix that, e.g. fully remove the vote?

It looks like there is no way to remove a vote after the buttons where pressed. Is that on purpose? A better idea might be maybe to allow to change the vote for 1-2 hours until it got fixed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change the vote for five minutes. After that, the vote can only be removed after the voted-upon question or answer has been edited. This is [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes).

If you accidentally voted, just click the button again to remove the vote, again within the five minute limit.